# Retrieving list of c# questions

Tags: support, api, questions, tags, api-v1

I am trying to retrieve list of C# questions using [http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.0/questions?title=true&tagged="c#"](http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.0/questions?title=true&tagged=%22c#%22).

But I get JSON response related to c questions.

**Response :**

```js
{
  "total": 24404,
  "page": 1,
  "pagesize": 30,
  "questions": [
    {
      "tags": [
        "c",
        "math",
        "float",
        "modulo",
        "interval"
      ],
      "answer_count": 4,
      "favorite_count": 0,
      "question_timeline_url": "/questions/4633177/timeline",
      "question_comments_url": "/questions/4633177/comments",
      "question_answers_url": "/questions/4633177/answers",
      "question_id": 4633177,
      "owner": {
        "user_id": 435129,
        "user_type": "registered",
        "display_name": "Ohmu",
        "reputation": 601,
        "email_hash": "05cfeb4116c85cbe70cd3003ee0e092c"
      },
      "creation_date": 1294476894,
      "last_edit_date": 1294491196,
      "last_activity_date": 1294491196,
      "up_vote_count": 0,
      "down_vote_count": 0,
      "view_count": 31,
      "score": 0,
      "community_owned": false,
      "title": "C: How to wrap a float to the interval [-pi, pi)"
    },
....
```

well if I try it for VB.Net [http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.0/questions?title=true&tagged="vb.net"] I get the right response.

I don't know what's wrong with the query string? Can some one point me in a right direction.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to encode the `#` character (to `%23`)

http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.0/questions?title=true&tagged=c%23

Comment: Maybe we should make an HTML entity chart so this is avoided in the future.